# Search component to filter products in vuex

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuex

I have created search component and its filtering array correctly, but when i load page for the first time products are not appearing on page.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cart: [],
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: []
  },
  getters: {
    cart: state => {
      return state.cart
    },
    products: state => {
      return state.products
    },
    filteredProducts: state => {
      return state.filteredProducts
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
      state.products = products
    },
    MORE_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
      // state.products = products
      state.filteredProducts = products
    },
    filterProducts(state, searchTerm) {
      return state.filteredProducts = state.products.filter((product) => {
        return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchProducts({ commit }) {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products?_limit=4&_page=1').then(res => {
        commit('SET_PRODUCTS', res.data)
      })
    },
    loadMore({commit}) {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products?_limit=8&_page=1').then(res => {
        commit('MORE_PRODUCTS', res.data)
      })
    },
    filterProducts({commit}, searchTerm) {
      commit('filterProducts', searchTerm)
    }
  }
})
```

Home component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="products-container">
            <div v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.name">
                <router-link class="link" to="/product">
                    <Product :product="product" />
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="load-more">
            <button class="btn" @click="this.$store.dispatch('loadMore')">UCITAJ VISE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Product from '../components/Product.vue'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: { Product },
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts')
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['showCart', 'products', 'filteredProducts'])
    }
}
</script>
```

Obviously products are not showing because in SET_PRODUCTS mutation i set 'products' to 'state.products'. Because filter method is creating new array i can't set products to state.filteredProducts, and i can't set in Home v-for="product in products", for the same reason, its not filtering at all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. All I had to do is add this line:

```
state.filteredProducts = products
```

In the `SET_PRODUCTS` function:

```
SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
      state.products = products
      state.filteredProducts = products
}
```

So it can properly show products when page is loaded.